# Calculating the difference between durations with milliseconds in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, datetime-conversion

> **TL;DR:** I need to get the difference between `HH:MM:SS.ms` and `HH:MM:SS.ms` as `HH:MM:SS:ms`

---

### What I need:

Here's a tricky one. I'm trying to calculate the difference between two timestamps such as the following:

```
In: 00:00:10.520
Out: 00:00:23.720
```

Should deliver:

```
Diff: 00:00:13.200
```

I thought I'd parse the times into actual `Time` objects and use the difference there. This works great in the previous case, and returns `00:0:13.200`.

### What doesn't work:

However, for some, this doesn't work right, as Ruby uses `usec` instead of `msec`:

```
In: 00:2:22.760
Out: 00:2:31.520
Diff: 00:0:8.999760
```

Obviously, the difference should be `00:00:8:760` and not `00:00:8.999760`. <sub>I'm really tempted to just `tdiff.usec.to_s.gsub('999','')` ……</sub>

---

### My code so far:

Here's my code so far (these are parsed from the input strings like "0:00:10:520").

```
tin_first, tin_second = ins.split(".")
tin_hours, tin_minutes, tin_seconds = tin_first.split(":")
tin_usec = tin_second * 1000
tin = Time.gm(0, 1, 1, tin_hours, tin_minutes, tin_seconds, tin_usec)
```

The same happens for `tout`. Then:

```
tdiff = Time.at(tout-tin)
```

For the output, I use:

```
"00:#{tdiff.min}:#{tdiff.sec}.#{tdiff.usec}"
```

Is there any faster way to do this? Remember, I just want to have the difference between two times. What am I missing?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p6 at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Time`:

```
require 'time' # Needed for Time.parse

def time_diff(time1_str, time2_str)
  t = Time.at( Time.parse(time2_str) - Time.parse(time1_str) )
  (t - t.gmt_offset).strftime("%H:%M:%S.%L")
end

out_time = "00:00:24.240"
in_time  = "00:00:14.520"

p time_diff(in_time, out_time)
#=> "00:00:09.720"
```

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on `Time`:

```
def slhck_diff( t1, t2 )
  ms_to_time( time_as_ms(t2) - time_as_ms(t1) )
end

# Converts "00:2:22.760" to 142760
def time_as_ms( time_str )
  re = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?/
  parts = time_str.match(re).to_a.map(&:to_i)
  parts[4]+(parts[3]+(parts[2]+parts[1]*60)*60)*1000
end

# Converts 142760 to "00:02:22.760"
def ms_to_time(ms)
  m = ms.floor / 60000
  "%02i:%02i:%06.3f" % [ m/60, m%60, ms/1000.0 % 60 ]
end

t1 = "00:00:10.520"
t2 = "01:00:23.720"
p slhck_diff(t1,t2)
#=> "01:00:13.200"

t1 = "00:2:22.760"
t2 = "00:2:31.520"
p slhck_diff(t1,t2)
#=> "00:00:08.760"
```

Comment: `parts = time_str.split(/[:\.]/).map(&:to_i)` ? (Parts then has 4 elements)

Comment: @steenslag Simpler, for sure. For some reason I go to regex before `split`. :) Better yet, I could have just split on `:` and used `to_f` (and slightly different math to add 'em up).

Answer (score 1):

I figured the following could work:

```
out_time = "00:00:24.240"
in_time = "00:00:14.520"
diff = Time.parse(out_time) - Time.parse(in_time)
Time.at(diff).strftime("%H:%M:%S.%L")
# => "01:00:09.720"
```

It *does* print `01` for the hour, which I don't really understand.

In the meantime, I used:

```
Time.at(diff).strftime("00:%M:%S.%L")
# => "00:00:09.720"
```

<sub>Any answer that does this better will get an upvote or the accept, of course.</sub>

Comment: The problem is because you're treating the diff as GMT but then displaying the time in your local time zone. My computer shows `"17:00:09.720"` as the result. See my answer for how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
in_time = "00:02:22.760"
out_time = "00:02:31.520"
diff = (Time.parse(out_time) - Time.parse(in_time))*1000
puts diff
```

OUTPUT:

```
8760.0 millliseconds
```

`Time.parse(out_time) - Time.parse(in_time)` gives the result in `seconds` so multiplied by `1000` to convert into `milliseconds`.

[image]

Comment: That does not work — at least for me. Have you tried it? I get an `invalid date` error. For example, testing `Date.strptime("00:2:22.760","%H:%M:%S.%L")` throws this error (Ruby 1.9.3p6)

Comment: updated the code. its working fine, i have tested in my machine